Conditional convergent series implies existence of rearrangement that diverges: Doesn't the sum of the negative terms tend to $-\infty$?
In the proof for the Riemann Series Theorem that I'm reading, the author is currently establishing the existence of a divergent rearrangement of an infinite series given that the original series converges non-absolutely. They do this by first separating the original series into its positive terms ($p_1, p_2, p_3$, etc.) and its negative terms ($q_1, q_2, q_3$, etc.) where $p_k$ is the $k$th positive term and $q_k$ is the $k$th negative term in the original series.
The author then constructs the following series,
$$[p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + ... + p_a] + q_1 + [p_{a+1} + p_{a+2} +...+ p_b] + q_2 + [p_{b+1}+...$$
In order words, the author constructs a block of positive terms in order, then inserts a negative term, starts another block of positive terms (continuing the order from the previous block), and then inserts the next negative term, so on and so forth.
Each block of positive terms sums to a number greater than $2^k$, where $k$ is equal to the index of the negative term that follows the block (e.g., $p_1 + p_2 + ... + p_a > 2^1$, since $q_1$ follows it).
This step is justified because since the original series is not absolutely convergent, $\sum{p_n}$ must diverge (and since it is monotone increasing, it must diverge to $+\infty$). Therefore we can sum as many positive terms as we want to get as large a number as we want.
However, the author then continues by saying that because the original series is convergent, all its terms must converge to $0$, and so all the negative terms must converge to 0. Therefore the negative terms "will not interfere with the goal of producing ever larger partial sums for the new series and so, evidently, this new series diverges to $+\infty$."
My understanding is this: If we take a partial sum that has a sufficiently large number of terms, stopping just before a negative term, then when we add that negative term to the partial sum it affects it very little, because that negative term is very small. On the other hand, we are definitely summing up blocks of positive numbers whose sums are growing geometrically, and therefore the overall rearranged series diverges to $+\infty$.
But I'm confused. Not converging absolutely implies that both $\sum{p_n}$ and $\sum{q_n}$ diverge. Since $\sum{p_n}$ is monotone increasing it must diverge to $+\infty$, and since $\sum{q_n}$ is monotone decreasing it must diverge to $-\infty$. When we take partial sums of the rearranged sequence for very large numbers of terms, we do sum up a number of $q_n$s, and this summation gets more and more negative the more terms involved in the partial sum. How are we so sure then that the overall rearranged series diverges to $+\infty$? I don't see how the fact that $q_n \to 0$ takes precedence over the fact that $\sum{q_n} \to -\infty$.

The individual positive terms are converging to 0 -- the blocks of them are getting much longer to make up for that, so that the block sums are still diverging.

If the negative terms come "too late" , we can ensure that the positive terms dominate (we can of course reach the same if we want a divergence towards $-\infty$).

@AlexK Is it not possible for the negative sum to diverge to $-\infty$ faster than the positive sum goes to $+\infty$, so as to counteract the longer lengths of the positive blocks?

@Peter How would one go about showing that more rigorously?

The fact $q_n\to 0$ precedes the fact $\sum_n q_n=-\infty$ because $(q_n)$ is a subsequence of the original sequence, say $(a_n)$, for which $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges. Then the $n$-th term test tells that $a_n\to 0$. Now, being subsequences of $(a_n)$, both $(p_n)$ and $(q_n)$ converge to $0$ as well.

@lightweaver I think it would be instructive to shift the burden of proof: You say you don't see why the fact that $q_n\to 0$ takes precedence over the fact that $\sum q_n=-\infty$. My question is: Given the author's construction, why would $\sum q_n=-\infty$ matter?

@user469053 Because it’s possible to take a partial sum of the new series that involves a large number of terms $q_n$, say $i$. That partial sum would equal the sum of the positive blocks $+ \sum^i_{n=1}{q_n}$ (with $i$ large). As $i$ gets larger and larger, $\sum^i_{n=1}{q_n}$ becomes more like $\sum^\infty_{n=1}{q_n}= -\infty$. So how can we so readily say that this contribution to the partial sum can be ignored?

You haven't shifted the burden of proof. You've still just said you don't see how $\sum q_n= -\infty$ doesn't matter. I'm asking you to try to construct a proof that it does matter.

Suppose that we have the rearrangement $$[p_1+p_2+\ldots+p_{n_1}]+q_1+[p_{n_1+1}+p_{n_1+2}+\ldots+p_{n_2}]+q_2+\ldots.$$  Let $n_0=0$, so the sum of the $k^{th}$ positive block is $\sum_{i=n_{k-1}+1}^{n_k}p_i>2^k$. Let $(b_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ be this rearranged sequence. Let $$s_n=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i$$ be the $n^{th}$ partial sum. Note that \begin{align*} \sum_{i=1}^{n_k+k} b_i & =[p_1+\ldots+p_{n_1}]+q_1+[p_{n_1+1}+p_{n_1+2}+\ldots + p_{n_2}]+q_2 \\ &+\ldots +[p_{n_{k-1}+1}+p_{n_{k-1}+2}+\ldots+p_{n_k}]+q_k.\end{align*}
Moreover, between $n_{k-1}+(k-1)$ and $n_k+(k-1)$, $s_n$ is strictly increasing because we're adding the $p_i$ terms. Then there is a dip of $q_k$ when we go from $n=n_k+(k-1)$ to $n=n_k+k$. Therefore the minimum value of $s_n$ on $[n_{k-1}+(k-1),n_k+k]$ is the minimum of its values at the endpoints: $$\min \{s_n:n\in [n_{k-1}+(k-1),n_k+k]\}=\min\{s_{n_{k-1}+(k-1)},s_{n_k+k}\}.$$  We also note that, as noted above, $$s_{n_k+k}=\sum_{i=1}^k\Biggl[\Bigl[\sum_{j=n_{i-1}+1}^{n_i}p_j\Bigr]+q_i\Bigr]\Biggr]\geqslant \sum_{i=1}^k [2^i-q_i].$$ Clearly this goes to $\infty$ as $k\to \infty$, because the terms $2^i-q_i$ grow to $\infty$.
The summary is a "tiny" downward step of $q_k$ will take the partial sum down a little, but not enough to counteract the huge steps upward that are accomplished by the positive blocks.
